# Dynamic query to find all the table DML activity in all the table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, dml

Hi I need to search the DML activity of specified list of tables in a schema

**single query**

```
select max(ora_rowscn),SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(max(ora_rowscn)) FROM 'TABLE_NAME'
```

since it is time consuming and hard to run individual queries ,so i am  trying to prepare a dynamic sql to fetch max(ora_rowscn),SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(max(ora_rowscn)) from all the tables so that i can use a filter and select a set of tables

**Query Template**

```
select 'with tmp(table_name, row_number) as (' from dual 
union all 
select 'select '''||table_name||''',count(*) from '||table_name||' union  ' from USER_TABLES 
union all
select 'select '''',0 from dual) select table_name,row_number from tmp order by row_number desc ;' from dual;
```

how do i used the max(ora_rowscn),SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(max(ora_rowscn)) for all the tables

any suggestions to correct the syntax of the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such a PLSQL code containing `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in order to get the desired values through Dynamic SQL

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE        
  v_rowscn NUMBER;
  v_tmstp  TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
 FOR c IN 
 (SELECT t.table_name FROM user_tables t)
 LOOP
  BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT max(ora_rowscn),SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(max(ora_rowscn)) FROM '||
                               c.table_name INTO v_rowscn, v_tmstp;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( c.table_name||' - max_scn : '|| v_rowscn||
                         ' - max_scn_timestamp : '|| v_tmstp );
   EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( sqlerrm );
  END;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

as long as any exception does not occur for each individual table.

Comment: ,Many thanks , but if  i need to filter on schema and list of tables ?

Comment: I don't know your rule for filtering, but just replace the query by adding a WHERE condition such as `... WHERE table_name LIKE 'R%'` in order to bring only the tables  start with the letter `R` @rakesh

Comment: for testing i have filtered on schema and as well as on a table the anonymous block completed but how to view the results ?

Comment: Did you issue `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before calling `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` @rakesh ?

Comment: oops i forgot to put that it works now , one question how to get timestamp value?

Comment: what's the problem with `v_tmstp` variable in the current case @rakesh ?

Comment: Many thanks for the logic and solution it worked after testing

Comment: nice, keep on proceeding ... you're welcome @rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion. I would not recommend using `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` for all tables, since it'll throw ORA-01405 a lot.

```
select 'with tmp(table_name, max_rscn, ct) as (' from dual 
union all 
select 'select '''||table_name||''',max(ora_rowscn), count(*) from '||table_name||' union  ' from USER_TABLES 
union all
select 'select '''',0,0 from dual) select table_name, max_rscn from tmp;' from dual;
```

Comment: @Kinfinity i need to fetch the data from both of these two columns max(ora_rowscn),SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(max(ora_rowscn)) for the selected tables